# How to get an average for each hours for the given time period using Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Something I'm trying on Pivot Table but haven't been able to. Not sure if it can be done or not, so thought I would ask the experts.

I have relatively small dataset in excel for Oct, Nov, and Dec with patient and the procedure canceled. I would like to know what is the average number of cancellation by hour for these 3 months. Here's the sample of the data:

```
Date        Appt Time   Rounded Time        Canc Reason Canc. Comments.                                                         Department      Procedure
10/25/2017   4:30 AM    10/25/17 4:00 AM    Other                                                                               NONINVASIVE     ECG 12-LEAD (CHEAT LAKE CLINIC ONLY) [ECG3047]
11/2/2017    6:25 AM    11/2/17 6:00 AM     Error                                                                               NONINVASIVE     ECG
11/21/2017   7:00 AM    11/21/17 6:00 AM    Other       per pt home health nurse--did not know about appt time                  NONINVASIVE     TTE
10/16/2017   7:15 AM    10/16/17 6:00 AM    Error       PVR just completed not needed Holiday RN                                NONINVASIVE     TEE
10/9/2017    7:15 AM    10/9/17 6:00 AM     Error       error in swcheduling - not needed per ordering                          NONINVASIVE     TTE
11/16/2017   7:30 AM    11/16/17 6:00 AM    Other       pt not coming                                                           NONINVASIVE     TEE
11/15/2017   7:30 AM    11/15/17 6:00 AM    Other                                                                               NONINVASIVE     HOLTER MONITOR
```

I want to create a Pivot Table based on this data. I want to know how many cancellation were done every couple of hours (based on `Rounded time`) for each procedure type. I can easily do the count on this, but that wouldn't give me an idea of how many `on average` we're getting cancellation on those hours. This would help us manage more patients if there are cancellations.

In this method, I had hours in columns and `procedure` and `cancellation reason` in rows; `cancellation reason` being under each `procedure`.

One method I applied is by adding a column called `count` with value `1` for all rows. Then I used that in Pivot table to get the `sum` of the `count`. This gave me the same result as above. When I did `Average` on this column, all I get is value `1`, and it makes sense why it's doing that.

So, the question is, how do I get an average of cancellation for these hours for the given time period? If it can't be done using Pivot Table, what's the other option I have that I can use to get the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your problem but in a helper column you could try something like :

=IF(Cancel=TRUE,1/COUNTIFS(Procedure range,Procedure,Hour range,Hour),0)